# DevEnvDir in VS2017 points to VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

In my extension project file I'v set Start Action to start Visual Studio by setting `StartPrograms`  in my project file (.vbproj if that matters)

```
<StartPrograms>$(DevEnvDir)devenv.exe</StartPrograms>
```

The problem is that when the project is open in VS2017 it opens VS2015 and in project properties I see:

[image: Project properties]

Is there something wrong with my project? Or do I undersant DevEnvDir wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> DevEnvDir in VS2017 points to VS2015

That because you set the Start external program is Visual Studio **2015**. And this info  **stored in** the `.csproj.user` file. If open that `.csproj.user` file in the same folder as project file, you will find following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
    <StartProgram>C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe</StartProgram>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

So, even if you specify the `StartPrograms` in the project file, but specify Start external program in the project property will overwrite it.

To resolve this issue, you should specify Start external program as Visual Studio 2017:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: THX. I should have noticed. Also the tag was wrong StartPrograms instead of StartProgram